# progress element transparent background

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, progress

i have a `<progress>` bar and i want to color its track with a `linear-gradient`.
the effect i want to achieve though is having some portions of it to be transparent, so i styled it this way

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {

background-image:
linear-gradient(
to right,
red 33%,
rgba(0,0,0,0) 33%,
rgba(0,0,0,0) 66%,
yellow 66%,
yellow 100%);

}
```

this renders as a grey bar in the 33% to 66% portion, instead of plain transparent. i've also tried using the value `transparent` but it does not seem to work. i still get a solid default color.

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0jaysLzu/

is it possible to apply transparency to the track of a `progress` element?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3qyjnpk2/ ?

Comment: @GCyrillus that works.. what did you do?

Comment: ok i got it.. background instead of background-image. thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer background-image: should be background:

long answer
You have

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {

background-image:
linear-gradient(
to right,
red 33%,
rgba(0,0,0,0) 33%,
rgba(0,0,0,0) 66%,
yellow 66%,
yellow 100%);

}
```

It should be

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {

background:
linear-gradient(
to right,
red 33%,
rgba(0,0,0,0) 33%,
rgba(0,0,0,0) 66%,
yellow 66%,
yellow 100%);

}
```